# Selenium 2 & Firefox profiles do not get applied

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i'm stuck, I'm running my script through a proxy which requires HTTP Authentication, however I can't authenticate with @:.. So I decided to create a profile that has the authentication plugin added for FireFox and make it auto input.

I've made the zip base64 file, as I'm running on OSX I used the following commands,

`zip -r profile 3rkomsuo.selenium`

`openssl base64 -in "profile.zip" -out "profile.zip.b64"`

The file is 24MBs tho(edit, disabled firebug and now it's only about 4MB, still no luck)? I only added 2 plugins, firebug and Auth plugin, that's tiny! Now I've put the file into my web directory, I'm running MAMP, and I send the profile as described.

```
$session = $web_driver->session('firefox', array("firefox_profile" => file_get_contents("profile.zip.b64")));
```

I've checked the POST, send a correct array, i've increased PHP POST size in php.ini to 64MBs just in case, however nothing works, still loads the basic(nothing set up) profile? If anyone could help you would be my hero as I've spent several hours debugging this without any luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to set up the profile, make sure you rename prefs.js to user.js and zip the folder contents for the profile, not the profile folder itself!

Answer (score -1):

If making profile is not working in your case then you can handle Authentication dialog by using **Autoit**.

```
Write a few line script in autoit.
Compile it to convert it in exe.
Call that exe before the line which causes the authentication dialog to appear.
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to run an exe on OSX?